# ESI ESU 1808 soundcard support

Tags: hardware, sound, drivers

I need to know if the ESI ESU 1808 soundcard will work on my ubuntu, before I buy it. I've tried to google some answer, but could not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the sound card is not compatible with Ubuntu (source: [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=sv&u=http://sv.dahnielson.com/2007/10/esi-esu-1808.html&ei=Ghe9TLa_Oo6IuAOKtcAp&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBYQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3DESI%2BESU%2B1808%2Blinux%26hl%3Den%26prmd%3Div)). However that post is from October, 2007 a lot may have changed. Have you thought about contacting the manufacturer/retailer directly? Most offer some form of pre-sales support. Conversely you may want to get an Asus Xonar instead which are known to work very will with linux (and are great sound cards).